# Expected size of the connected component containing a randomly selected node

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Given an [Erdős–Rényi random graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) with n nodes and edge probability p, what is the expected number of nodes in the connected component containing a randomly selected node?

In other words, if I randomly select one node in the graph, how many nodes should I expect to be in the connected component it is a member of?

Comment: Is p a constant, or a function of n?

Comment: p is some constant independent of n. Ideally I'd like to know the expected size of the connected component containing a randomly selected node as a function of p and n.

Comment: If n is arbitrarily large, the graph is w.h.p connected and the question loses its point. When n is also a constant, it requires some thinking. Will try to.

Comment: yeah, I'm interested in the behavior for arbitrary finite values of n. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, by symmetry, the distribution of the component containing a randomly selected node is the same as the distribution of the component containing some generic fixed vertex.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C(n,p)$ be the probability of an $n$-node  [Erdős–Rényi random graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) with edge probability p being connected. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584228/exact-probability-of-random-graph-being-connected) we know that:

$C(n,p) = 1$ if $n=1$ (one node graphs are trivially connected)

$C(n,p) = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} C(i,p) {n-1 \choose i-1}  (1-p)^{i(n-i)}$ otherwise.

Let $P(k, p, n)$ be the probability that our node of interest is the member of an exactly $k$ node cluster in an $n$-node Erdős–Rényi random graph with edge probability $p$. $P$ can be calculated from $C$ as:

$P(k, p, n) = C(k,p) {n-1 \choose k-1} (1-p)^{k(n-k)}$

Then from $P$ we can calculate the desired expected value as:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} P(k, p, n) \times k$