# Probability that a random graph on countably many vertices is connected

Tags: probability, random-graphs, infinite-graphs

Fix $0 < p < 1$ and let $G$ be a random graph on elements $\mathbb{N}$ where for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, the probability that there is an edge between $n$ and $m$ will $p$. What is the probability (in terms of $p$) that $G$ will be connected?

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584228/exact-probability-of-random-graph-being-connected   Edit: nevermind I misread the question I wasn't thinking about infinite graphs.

Comment: Hint: you can actually prove that between every pair of distinct vertices there is (with probability 1) a path of length 2.

Comment: @DavidHackenger Well that's that. If you type that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you can actually prove that between every pair of distinct vertices there is a path of length 2 (with probability 1).