# Expected size of largest connected component

Tags: expected-value, random-graphs

I have a sample space of all the undirected graphs having *n* vertices and *m* edges. Then what is the expected value of the size of the largest connected component?

My original problem is that using the *G(n, p)* model (family of graphs having *n* vertices and any two vertices would be joined by an edge with probability *p*. See: [Erdős–Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model)), I need to calculate the expected size of the largest connected component in G(n, p). If the above problem can be solved then this original problem can be easily solved.

PS: I need to exactly calculate the value of the expectation for any fixed *n* and *p* given in the input and not just upper or lower bounds.

Comment: To be blunt, computing an exact value seems hopeless. Compare it to the problem of finding the [exact probability of the graph being connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584228/exact-probability-of-random-graph-being-connected), which is much easier and already has a complicated recursive formula.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah I know that would be much computationally intensive, but I only need that for small values of *n*.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question as I have solved the original problem.
The solution is extremely computationally intensive.

Let *S* be our required expected size of the largest connected component in G(n, p). and let $P_i^n$ be the probability that a graph of *n* vertices formed from G(n, p) have the largest connected component(s) of size $i$. then

$$S = \sum_{i = 1}^{i = n}iP_i^n$$

Now, for the calculation for $P_i^n$, first choose a set of $i$ vertices and define the below terms

- $f_i$ = the probability that a specific set of **already chosen** $i$ vertices is connected
- $g_i^n$ = the probability that no vertex from the set of $i$ chosen vertices make an edge to other remaining $(n-i)$ vertices.

Then $P_i^n$ would be
$$P_i^n = \binom{n}{i} f_i g_i^n \sum_{j = 1}^{j = i} P_j^{n - i} $$

This gives a recursive relation for $P_i^n$ (Note that in the summation term would go for $j = i$ and not for $j = i - 1$ as there can be more than one connected component of size *i* can be possible.

**Calculation for $g_i^n$**
$g_i$ can be easily calculated as the probability of not forming an edge between two vertices is $1 - p$ and there are total $i * (n - i)$ possible edges which shouldn't be formed, thus
$$g_i^n = (1 - p)^{i(n - i)}$$

**Calculation for $f_i$**
The calculation of $f_i$ is described here: [Exact probability of random graph being connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584228/exact-probability-of-random-graph-being-connected)
$$f_i = 1 - \sum_{k = 1}^{i - 1}f_k \binom{i - 1}{k - 1} (1 - p)^{k(i - k)}$$

The calculation of $f_i$ is also recursive. Overall the exact calculation for the required expectation $S$ is much computationally intensive.

Practically, generating a random set of graphs from the G(n, p) model, and calculating the average size of the largest connected component using DFS/BFS would be much easier than the exact method.