# Random graphs: Show that $\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \mathrm{diam} \biggl(G \biggl(n,\sqrt{\frac{2\log(n)+h}{n}} \biggr)\biggr) > 2 \biggr] = \mathcal{o}(1)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs

> Let $diam(G)$ denote the diameter of a graph $G$; i.e.
>
> $$\mathrm{diam}(G) := \max_{ { i,j} \in \binom{[n]}{2}} d(i, j)$$
>
> , where $d(i,j)$ denotes the length of the shortest path between the vertices $i$ and $j$. Show that for any $h(n) = \omega(1)$ and (at the same time) $h(n) = \mathcal{o}(\log(n))$ holds
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \mathrm{diam} \biggl(G \biggl(n,\sqrt{\frac{2\log(n)+h}{n}} \biggr)\biggr) > 2 \biggr] = \mathcal{o}(1).$$

So by the definiton of small-Oh we need to show that

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg[\mathrm{diam} \biggl(G \biggl(n,\sqrt{\frac{2\log(n)+h}{n}} \biggr)\biggr) > 2 \biggr] \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0.$$

However, I do not see how to evaluate the probability for the size of $diam$. Could you please give me a hint?

**Edit:**

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584228/exact-probability-of-random-graph-being-connected) the probability, say $f(n)$, for $G(n,p)$ to be disconnected can be recursively described as:

$$f(n) = 1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}f(i){n-1 \choose i-1}(1-p)^{i(n-i)}$$

Furthermore, I think the probability of two vertices $i$ and $j$ to have exactly one common neighbour should be

$$\frac{2\log(n)+h}{n} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-3} \biggl( 1- \sqrt{\frac{2\log(n)+h}{n}} \biggr).$$

Comment: You're really estimating the probability that every pair of vertices is adjacent or has a common neighbor. You want this probability to be $1-o(1)$. Can you figure out what the probability is for a fixed pair, as a function of $p$? Now try to show that with high probability every pair is good. That's probably what the mysterious $h$ in your expression is for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I made an edit to my question.